# What is the most efficient way to know that a Kafka event is visible in a K-Table?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, ktable

We use Kafka topics as both events and a repository. Using the kafka-streams API we define a simple K-Table that represents all the events in the topic.

In our use case we publish events to the topic and subsequently reference the K-Table as the backing repository. The main issue is that the published events are not immediately visible on the K-Table.

We tried transactions and exactly once semantics as described here (https://kafka.apache.org/26/documentation/streams/core-concepts#streams_processing_guarantee) but there is always a delay we cannot control.

- Publish Event
- Undetermined amount of time
- Published Event is visible in the K-Table

Is there a way to eliminate the delay or otherwise know that a specific event has been consumed by the K-Table.

NOTE: We tried both partition and global tables with similar results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because Kafka is an asynchronous system the observed delay is expected and you cannot do anything to avoid it.

However, if you publish a message to a topic, the `KafkaProducer` allows you to pass in a `Callback` to the `send()` method and the callback will be executed after the message was written to the topic providing the record's metadata like topic, partition, and offset.

After Kafka Streams processed messages, it will eventually commit the offsets (you can configure the commit interval, too). Thus, you can know if the message is in the `KTable` after the offset was committed. By default, committing happens every 30 seconds only and it's not recommended to use a very short commit interval because it implies large overhead. Thus, I am not sure if this would help for your case, as it seem you want a more timely "response".

As an alternative, you can also disable caching on the `KTable` and use a `toStream().process()` step -- after each update to the `KTable`, the changelog stream provided by `toStream()` will contain the record and you can access the record metadata (including its offset) in the `Processor` via the given `ProcessorContext` object. Thus should also allow you to figure out, when the record is available in the `KTable`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Matthias. I will try what you mention on your last paragraph.